# Requesting for Finite Difference Methods reference in Portuguese or English

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-difference, reference-request

<sub>[Crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4383153) on Mathematics SE</sub>

---

I have been assigned a group project for an introductory Linear Algebra subject on Finite Difference Methods and sparse matrices. Our professor advised we use Gilbert Strang's *Linear Algebra and its Applications* and G. D. Smith's *Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations*. However, not all our group members are fluent in English, and we are finding the material hard to tackle since it involves PDEs, and we haven't even seen ODEs yet. So, my request is for a collection of references that cover FDMs, of which some must be in Portuguese, and some references on the prior knowledge necessary to understand FDMs (not necessarily in Portuguese).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have operational knowledge of Portuguese, so I have a limited ability to judge the quality of the resources on this topic I have in my collection. It would be good to have another answer from a computational scientist who regularly uses Portuguese. However, this is what I had touched before in my life:

- [CalculoNumerico](https://github.com/reamat/CalculoNumerico) a GitHub page for [this project](https://www.ufrgs.br/reamat/CalculoNumerico/) devoted to collaborative effort for writing about numerical methods. I did not find it too useful for my needs, but not being a non-Portuguese speaker limits my ability to make use of it.
- [D. C. Lobão, "Introdução aos métodos numéricos"](https://www.professores.uff.br/diomarcesarlobao/wp-content/uploads/sites/85/2017/09/note6.pdf) on the other hand is quite a useful for the prior knowledge necessary to understand FDM. I would recommend it.

That material contains a list of older (without making any inference on the quality) references, which I have no access to, but I will list them here verbatim:

- BARROSO, Leônidas C. et. al., Cálculo Numérico (com Aplicações), 2a
  edição, Editora Harbra, São Paulo, 1987.
- CLAUDIO, Dalcidio M., MARINS, Jussara M., Cálculo Numérico Computacional, 2a edição, Atlas, 1994.
- SANTOS, Vitoriano R. B., Curso de Cálculo Numérico, 4a
  edição, LTC, 1982
- RUGGIERO, Márcia A. G., LOPES, Vera Lúcia R., Cálculo Numérico: Aspectos Teóricos e Computacionais, 2a edição, Makron Books, São Paulo, 1996.
- CAMPOS, R. J. A., Cálculo Numérico Básico. 1ª edição, Atlas, 1978.
- CAMARGO, W. C. M., Apostila de Cálculo Numérico. Departamento de Informática. UFPR.